# Java JAR File Questions on Stack Overflow - how can I handle asking about specific issues for them?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I have a Java JAR file that doesn't execute on two of my machines with the newest JDK Java SE installed, yet it runs perfectly well on a friends PC.

What I hope is that if I ask SO users to open the file they can shed some light on **why** it doesn't run. (Possibly) E.g. if I upload the file and a user downloads it ~ then tells me the issue is a memory leak according to certain diagnostics I know what the problem is.

---

Can I provide a link to the JAR on a SO question to see why it doesn't work?

What other site can I ask to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Questions that ask "why doesn't this run" don't usually fair well.  Asking people to download a file from a random link to test will be less likely to get a lot of support.  But personally, when a JAR doesn't run for me, it is a local java issue that a reinstall usually fixes.

Comment: In general though, Stack Overflow is not a support site.  If you need tech support for a specific application (or jar), it is best to ask the developer of the application.

Comment: I agree - I think I should contact the developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a fan of downloading someone else's JAR, executing it, and seeing if it "works", for some value of "work".  Not to assume the worst, but if you *didn't* get my credit card information and the password to my bank account, would that mean your JAR didn't work?  :P

It feels like the question you're asking is missing two key aspects:

- What is really meant by "doesn't run"?  Does it not start?  Does it fail to execute?

  - Providing more clarity into why it doesn't run would be a start.  Stack traces and error messages are **helpful**.
- Are there architectural differences between your and your friends' machines (x86/AMD-64/PPC/ARM)?

  - If there are, then that would be another place to start.  Ensure that the difference isn't between architectures.
- Is it a JAR that you control?

  - Be prepared to make changes to it, if the structure is fundamentally flawed.

The big thing here is **don't post your JAR**.  You won't endear people to look at the problem.  You can provide the structure of your JAR and a MANIFEST.MF file, as well as any relevant error messages.  But be prepared to do most of the legwork yourself.